# PHP Search filter sort results alphabetically

Tags: php, joomla

I'm working on a little webcatalog with a search function. I'm using the software Eshop in Joomla. There is a filter function for manufacturers, but these results aren't displayed alphabetically.

I've looked around for solutions, but I can't get it working. This is the code:

```
<?php
if (!empty($filterData['manufacturer_ids'])){
    $manufacturerIds = $filterData['manufacturer_ids'];
}
else{
    $manufacturerIds = array();
}

foreach ($manufacturers as $manufacturer){?>
    <li>
        <label class="checkbox">
            <input class="manufacturer" onclick="eshop_ajax_products_filter('manufacturer');" type="checkbox" name="manufacturer_ids[]" value="<?php echo $manufacturer->manufacturer_id; ?>" <?php if (in_array($manufacturer->manufacturer_id, $manufacturerIds)) echo 'checked="checked"'; ?>>
            <?php echo $manufacturer->manufacturer_name; ?><span class="badge badge-info"><?php echo $manufacturer->number_products;?></span>
        </label>
    </li>
<?php }?>
```

Can anyone help me?

[This is the current view](https://www.nvsdomein.nl/kjh/schilderijen)

Comment: Did you try to use the `sort` function ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`sort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) function and I would suggest using the `SORT_STRING` optional parameter to give you the following.

```
$manufacturers = sort($manufacturers, SORT_STRING);
```

> This function sorts an array. Elements will be arranged from lowest to highest when this function has completed.
>
> ...
>
> SORT_STRING - compare items as strings

**Edit:**

After confirming the data structure, this is an array of objects and requires a custom sorting function. Therefore, you should use [`usort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php).

> This function will sort an array by its values using a user-supplied
>   comparison function. If the array you wish to sort needs to be sorted
>   by some non-trivial criteria, you should use this function.

So you first define the function that compares the strings for the `manufacturer_name` property.

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    return strcmp($a->manufacturer_name, $b->manufacturer_name);
}

usort($manufacturers , "cmp");
```

Comment: Where exactly do I have to add this code? I tried adding it above foreach ($manufacturers as $manufacturer) but then I get an error on the page

Comment: If you visit the website link, you can see what happens

Comment: Thnx, this is working! Couldn't have found this myself!